# How to find the Text Area(Height/Width) of TextView programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, layoutparams

I have an `EditText`, a `Button` and a `TextView`. On clicking the button, textview shows the text written in edittext. Is it possible to find the size of textview occupied depending upon text. i.e. If It has three characters "**abc**", what is width now, if it has 5 characters like "**abcde**" , then what is the width ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),bounds);
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width();
```

or

```
textView.setText("bla");
textView.measure(0, 0);
textView.getMeasuredWidth();
textView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: This works quite nicely - until the text is too long to fit into one line and wraps, adding a second line. Since getTextBounds() does not know about the space available for a line of text, the calculated height will be severely underestimating the actual height.

Answer (score 11):

Please try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setTextSize(20);       
    edit.setText("Hello, world");       
    edit.measure(0, 0);
    int width = edit.getMeasuredWidth();
    Log.w("width", width.toString());
}
```

Before you get width, you have to measure the view / label / text edit.
Please let me know if this is not working.

Comment: Both of the answers are correct , yours and the above one...Thnx its working.

Comment: Plese mark as answer (the button below down-vote)

And i'm glad it worked.

Comment: This will return 0 because the view has not been drawn yet. It has to be done in a Runnable in `view.post()` for you to get the dimensions

Answer (score 7):

```
TextView txt = new TextView(mContext);
txt.setText("Some Text)";
int height = txt.getLineCount() *  txt.getLineHeight();
int width = txt.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
yourTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
     int width = yourTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
     int height = yourTextView.getMeasuredHeight();

   }
});
```

Comment: Hello @M D, can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196894/how-to-get-list-item-data-in-bindview-when-clicking-on-radiobutton-in-android

Answer (score 2):

please tell me width in??? do you want ?

`TextView` method `getWidth()` gives you width of your view, in pixels

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.getWidth(); //width of your view, in pixels
```

Comment: I meant to find the width depending upon text.