# Get exact width of a textview in pixel programmatically (Android)

Tags: java, android, textview, width, pixel

Using android, does anybody know how to get the exact width of a textview, in pixel, before it's displayed on the screen ? (programmatically)
I've search a lot on the internet but I didn't found anything working.

Thank you

Links of the post I tried :

  [With a Paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android)

  [With measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359538/how-to-find-the-text-areaheight-width-of-textview-programmatically-in-android)

  [With density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232541/android-measuretext-return-pixels-based-on-scaled-pixels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was better that you had sent some code. Then we could help you more.
But I think that you may use these methods:

```
yourText.measure(0, 0);
```

And then these codes:

```
int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that this way didn't work but in fact my code was bad... Thank you very much for your quick answer

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` which is usually used to find out the height and the width of views before they are drawn.

For example,

```
yourTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

      yourTextView.getWidth();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
textView.setText("your text");
textView.measure(0, 0);
textView.getMeasuredWidth();
textView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

As ***Nargess*** said you'd better use methods of measuring view's width and height, like code below:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
view.measure(size.x, size.y);
int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```