# Measure TextView height - auto wrap

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-view, measure

I've created an expandable cardview, which contains a title, subtitle and a detail textview.

Now I want to get the height dynamically depending on the height of the text in a textview with `wrap_content`. So I used the `.measure` method on my view in the onClickListener:

```
holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           holder.getDetailText().measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           Log.i("Project", ""+ holder.getDetailText().getMeasuredHeight());
    }

});
```

I get a height of **57** with this text:

```
holder.getDetailText().setText("Test Test Test Test");
```

If I now add a longer text in there which automatically wraps to multiple lines I get the same height of **57**

```
holder.getDetailText().setText("Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test ...");
```

As soon as I put a text with new line feed in there everything works as expected which results in a height of **155**

```
holder.getDetailText().setText("Test\nTest\nTest");
```

So how is it possible to get the actually height of the textview with automatically wrapped text?

**Update**:
This is a very long text which is automatically wrapped, but I get the height of 57, so it will only display the first line, because the `getMeasuredHeight` only returns this (57) height.
[image]

What I expect, but doesn't work, because the `getMeasuredHeight` returns the wrong height:
[image]

If I manually put `\n` feed, so there is no auto-wrap `getMeasuredHeight` returns the right height and everything works as expected.
[image]

It seems that the `.measure` ignores the width, because even if I put there a constant value the height returned by `getMeasuredHeight` wont't change.

Comment: when you need to calculate the height of textView. can you please specify scenario so I can help you

Comment: I've a recyclerview which items expand depending on the height and the amount of text in the textview, so the expanded height will fit the text.

Comment: how is it possible to get the actually height of the textview with automatically wrapped text?  means what exactly automatically mean by

Comment: If you put a very long text in a textview, Android automatically put the long text in multiple lines.

Comment: so, textview size increases or if it will go next line then you want to get the height of textView ? Can you attach screenshoot if possible

Comment: Not sure of what you are asking, it is your width that is resizing, not your height. Wouldn't it be constant? If I am mistaken and you really do need the height, then it is probably your approach. Get the measured height of the parent view. See if that helps.

Comment: I've added some pictures, maybe it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For long texts, TextView takes a certain amount of time to render. So before that we are calculating the height of that TextView

Use the following code:

```
view.setText("Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test ...");

view.getViewTreeObserver()
    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Height :- " + view.getMeasuredHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Please refer to [How to find the Text Area(Height/Width) of TextView programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359538/how-to-find-the-text-areaheight-width-of-textview-programmatically-in-android)

If you want to see exact behavior of TextView then create a CustomTextView and see how their lifecycle behaves.

Please let me know if it dosen't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether you have figured out a solution for this,
the solution is when you are measuring height with definite width specified
you need to be very careful with the width (because the calculation is very precise) if you are not getting desired height that means you are missing something in your spec,

example is below

```
val widthMeasureSpec =
      View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ceil(context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_width)).toInt(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    val heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED).
```

in the above code what you pass matter for the width parameter,

- you need pass the exact width that you have passed for your textview
- you need to pass measure spec as `View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` in my case